# HTTP POST request using form-data in java returns 400

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-post

I am making a post request in java and getting 400 as response code. However constructing the same request in Postman gives 200.[image: Postman reuest and response]

Here is my Java code I use for making the request:-

```
    final URI baseUri = new URIBuilder("localhost:8080/api/service?ask=true&uid=user&pp=secret").build();
    final URIBuilder applicationUriBuilder = new URIBuilder(baseUri);
    URI applicationURI = applicationUriBuilder.build();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(applicationURI);
    
    File resumeFile = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:/data/2655386.docx").getFile(); 
StringBody userDetailsString = new StringBody(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(userProfileDetails), MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(resumeFile, DEFAULT_BINARY);
    
    MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    entityBuilder.addPart("props",userDetailsString);
    entityBuilder.addPart("file",fileBody);
    entityBuilder.addTextBody("contentField","CONTENT");
    HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    httpPost.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE);
    httpPost.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT,"*/*");
    CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost))
    String json = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
```

I get this error

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 400 Bad Request</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 400</h2>
<p>Problem accessing localhost:8080/api/service?ask=true&uid=user&pp=secret. Reason:
<pre>    Bad Request</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

can someone suggest what is wrong with the code? Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe 'content-type'(MIME type) mismatch throws this error. Postman doesn't block this issue but browsers are very strict with 'content-type' issues. Can you share 'Headers' tab image from Postman?

Comment: headers is blank in postman as you can see in image. however in the curl request header is  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -H 'postman-token: 333231ef-55ee-c6b3-73fa-6eb21e454685' \

Comment: @Md.KawserHabib you were right it was happening due to content-type mismatch. when I added content-type: "*/*"  it worked. Any explanation for this?

Comment: I have written a detailed explanation in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **'content-type'**(MIME type) mismatch throws this error. Postman doesn't block this issue but browsers are very strict with 'content-type' issues. For the file type, it will be multipart/form-data.

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
```

To reduce security risk browser check request and response MIME Type. If they mismatch, then browser/serverside block the content/content-delivery. This is a security feature. From client-side like a browser, you can stop MIME type checking. This is also true for the server-side. But it increases security risk.

From **wiki** we can find a basic idea of the security risk,

Content sniffing, also known as **media type sniffing** or **MIME sniffing**, is the practice of inspecting the content of a byte stream to attempt to deduce the file format of the data within it. Content sniffing is generally used to compensate for a lack of accurate metadata that would otherwise be required to enable the file to be interpreted correctly. Content sniffing techniques tend to use a mixture of techniques that rely on the redundancy found in most file formats: looking for file signatures and magic numbers, and heuristics including searching for well-known representative substrings, the use of byte frequency, and n-gram tables, and Bayesian inference.

More aboute MIME Type you can read this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types).

Comment: @ak1234, Is this answer helpful?